# how to obtain SecIdentityRef from SecCertificateRef and PrivateKey?

Tags: ios, iphone, keychain

How to create a SecIdentityRef if you have a SecCertificateRef and Private Key in iOS?
I have a X509 certificate which is passed from server and an associated private key, but now I am struggling to establish trust in `NSURLCredentials`.

A similar question was asked here 
[How to establish a SecIdentityRef in an iPhone keychain ? (Without a .p12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241590/how-to-establish-a-secidentityref-in-an-iphone-keychain-without-a-p12)

As mentioned IMPORTANT in above post, i did create SecCertificateRef using `SecCertificateCreateWithData` first and then added into the keychain using `SecItemAdd` but don't know what to do now to generate SecIdentityRef.

Many Thanks,
Manish

P.S. -  I don't have enough ref points to comment on a post so asking a new question.

Comment: Hi, have you succeeded? I'm doing the same, but I cant get it working, I'm sending CSR to server, server returns client cert, I will save it in keychain, then I want to perform request so I overwrote  `credentialWithIdentity:certificates:persistence` but im still getting SSL errors

Answer (score 5):

As I understand it, `SecIdentityRef`s don't exist as individual keychain entries. When you get an identity using `SecItemCopyMatching()`, it finds a certificate and a corresponding private key and returns an identity which is just a reference to that (cert, key) pair. As far as I know the only way to create `SecIdentityRef` is to insert a private key and a certificate for that key into your keychain and then perform a search for identities.