# Is it possible to create a SecIdentityRef from public and private key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, security, keychain

I'm working on an iOS app which needs to use certificates in order to to encrypt and decrypt data.

I was able to create the public and private key using the [documentation Apple provides](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CertKeyTrustProgGuide/iPhone_Tasks/iPhone_Tasks.html) but I'm not able to find a way to create a `SecIdentityRef` from those keys

Is it possible?

Comment: You probably already understand this: If you are encryption data most likely you really need to use a symmetric algorithm such as AES. The issues are that asymmetric encryption is dog-slow and the data length is limited to the key size. Asymmetric key encryption is usually used to encrypt symmetric keys for transport.

Comment: That's true, but I'm tied to this because I'm also using the Multipeer framework that uses certificate identity in order to provide a secure communication channel...

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26458540/how-to-obtain-secidentityref-from-seccertificateref-and-privatekey/

Comment: @wiml mm, no it's not. The question you mention assumes a certificate reference is given, this question is more around creating self signed certificates on the device...

Answer (score -1):

Is difficulty how to create a certificate (possibly inside a SecIdentity, possibly a SecCertificateRef, possibly as a DER-encoded CFDataRef) given a public and private key?