# how can I use build URLCredential with 2 perm file?

Tags: swift, ssl, ssl-certificate, nsurlsession, nsurlcredential

I have one piece of python code that need to transfer into swift code. I see lots of example using URLSessionDelegate and URLCerdentital. I see the signure for  URLCredential is `.init(identity: <#T##SecIdentity#>, certificates: <#T##[Any]?#>, persistence: <#T##URLCredential.Persistence#>)` for URLCredential. For me, how can I pass the `identity` part if I have two file path?

```
cert_file_path = "cert.pem"
key_file_path = "key.pem"
```

```py
import requests
cert_file_path = "cert.pem"
key_file_path = "key.pem"

url = "https://example.com/resource"
params = {"param_1": "value_1", "param_2": "value_2"}
cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)
r = requests.get(url, params=params, cert=cert)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, add the identity into the keychain:

[How to establish a SecIdentityRef in an iPhone keychain ? (Without a .p12)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4241590/how-to-establish-a-secidentityref-in-an-iphone-keychain-without-a-p12)

by adding the private key and then adding the certificates.

Then pull the SecIdentityRef out of the keychain and use it to create a credential by using NSURLCredential's `credentialWithIdentity:certificates:persistence:` class method.